# C# 2.0 - List processing

Tags: c#, list

In C# 3.0 for ,Removiing duplicates I can use

```
       int[] ints={1,1,2,34,5,6,7,5,11,13};
       List<int> integes = new List<int>();
       List<int> filter = new List<int>();
       integes.AddRange(ints);
       filter = integes.Distinct().ToList();
       filter.ForEach((i)=> { Console.WriteLine(i); });
```

Is similar shortcut method is available in ASP.NET 2.0 .

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335590/removing-duplicate-string-from-list-net-2-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
integes.ForEach(delegate(int i) {if(!filter.Contains(i)) {filter.Add(i);}});
```

Comment: So, why is `for (...) { ... }` evil and `list.ForEach(...)` good?

Comment: Note that this solution is O(n^2) if there are no duplicates. If the list is small or contains lots of duplicates it will be reasonably fast, but its time performance will inevitably be terrible if the list is large and duplicates are few. If you're in that situation, consider using a hash table to check for duplicates; hash tables are highly optimized for duplicate detection.

Answer (score 0):

Loop .Adds intead of an .AddRange and check for integes.Contains(int) in the loop.